# Miller Columns for Qt?

Tags: python, user-interface, qt4, pyqt

Is there an easy way to have an iTunes like interface (with [Miller Columns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns)) in Qt4 or do I have to create a MillerColumnWidget by myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm new to the term "Miller Columns", but descriptions suggest that the [QColumnView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolumnview.html) would be suitable.